# Projecting image on character

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a project where I have a character walking in front of a projector screen. Like the one you see in classrooms. I also have a projector which is projecting an image onto it using the Projector component.

Now my question: I know how to have the image projected on my character, but I was wondering if it's possible to do this more realistically, because now it's more of an on-off type situation. I kind of want the image to change on the character as it walks in front of the projection.

Is this possible? And if it is, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible!

Turns out I had my projector shader set to diffuse, so it just slammed the texture on everything it hit. I set that to Projector/light and it got better.
After that I set the texture itself to clamp instead of multiply at it's own settings. That fixed the multiply problem.
Last thing was to edit the image to have a white border around it, because it was repeating the edges. Now it's perfect!

Hope this helps anyone searching this.